# Attach custom data in Redirect to Route and retrieve in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When my ModelState is Valid I do this to scroll to a certain area:

```
var url = Url.RouteUrl(new { controller = "Controller", action = "Index" });
                return Redirect(url + "#anchor" + viewModel.Id);
```

Now I want to attach data to this Response and check in my razor view:

```
  @if(@Request.Url.property == MyData)
            {

            }
```

how can I go this?

I fear when I attach some custom string to the url that my "go to anchor" feature will break...

Could I use the headers for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data across a redirect using the [ControllerBase.TempData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx) property. This is a key-value-pair indexable object that persists data across a single HTTP request. E.g.

```
TempData["name"] = "John Doe";
TempData["address"] = new Address { Line1 = "123 Street", Line2 = "Town" };
```

See the following guide on how to use it: http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

Comment: how do you ask for TempData in the razor view? When I set ViewBag.IsActive = true in my controller its always NULL in my razor view. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It would behoove you learn how HTTP as a protocol works. ASP.NET tends to make you think all kinds of things are possible because it's just classes and methods and you can virtually do anything you want in just straight C#. However, it's fundamentally limited by the platform it runs on, in this case, the web.

A redirect is a type of server response that just includes a URL that the client should retrieve instead of the one it initially requested. Once this type of response is received by something like a web browser, it issues another GET request to that URL. The important part here is that redirects always result in a GET request.

With a GET request, you have only one method of passing any sort of data: the URL itself. Generally, this happens via a query string (the `?foo=bar` jazz you see at the end of some URLs). As a result, a fundamental limitation is that you can only pass scalar data as part of key value pairs. In other words, passing a datum named `foo` with a value of `"bar"`, is perfectly fine, but passing a value of an entire C# object *is not possible*. If you needed the entire object, you would have to flatten it, such that each property on that object is a separate  name-value pair in the query string.

So, going back to your code here, if you want to pass some additional data, you would do something like the following:

```
var url = Url.Action("Index", "Controller", new { foo = "bar" })
```

That would result in a URL similar to: /Controller/Index?foo=bar

If you need to add a fragment (the `#foo` piece of the URL), then that would be added to the end of the URL, after the query string, not before.

Comment: When I do in the anonym object name "Thats me" then the hash-tag which should come at the end is somehow removed when I look into Request.Url its not there anymore but I see url?name="Thats me" ?